# R round exponential number

Tags: r, rounding, stat

I just trying to round in R number like:

```
> round(1.327076e-09)
```

I would like it to result in

```
> 1.33e-09
```

but results in

```
> 0
```

which function can use?

Comment: Why should it return `1.32e-09` shouldn't it be `1.33e-09`? Or do you want to just truncate the number after the second dp?

Answer (score 20):

Try [`signif`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Round):

[image]

```
> signif(1.326135235e-09, digits = 3)
[1] 1.33e-09
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `signif`:

```
x <- 1.327076e-09 
signif(x,3)
[1] 1.33e-09
```

or `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%.2e",x)
[1] "1.33e-09"
```

Comment: Good call with `sprintf`.  In general, you only want to lose precision when displaying numbers, not in the actual calculations. `round` and `signif` should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 2):

The function `round` will do rounding and you can specify the number of decimals:

```
x <- 1.327076e-09
round(x, 11)
[1] 1.33e-09
```

Rising to the challenge set by @Joris and @GavinSimpson - to use `trunc` on this problem, do the following:

```
library(plyr)
round_any(x, 1e-11, floor)
[1] 1.32e-09
```

Comment: You can add trunc() to do what the OP is doing (not what he's asking).

Comment: Ding dong! That's the function that sprung to mind when I saw the desired output, but I figured rounding in OP's questions supersedes the output specified.

Comment: @Joris but how to get `trunc()` to work here: `> trunc(1.327076e-09)
[1] 0`?